# Highlight row with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change table row color when a radio button is checked in that row:

```
$(".myCheckbox").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("highlightRow", this.checked);
});
```

For some reason when I use FireBug to see the result I see the following on check:

```
<tr class="highlightRow .highlightRow">
```

How do I end-up with two classes and one with a dot?

CSS

```
.highlightRow {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Also tried:

```
.highlightRow TD {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the original HTML?  There's a good chance that you have something like this in there: `<tr class=".hightlightRow">`

Answer (score 0):

You must have been writing `.highlightRow` anywhere in your Javascript or anywhere in your original HTML. Please check again or post all Javascript and all HTML.

And aside form that: [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057453/how-to-highlight-the-selected-row-in-a-table-using-jquery) is better by far. ;)

Comment: Just curious, why do you think is a better solution?

Comment: I supposed that he is doing a select operation.

Comment: That solution is not that great.  Seeing $(this) over and over makes my brain go crazy.  Why do people not do `var $this = $(this);` more?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the code works without adding a second parameter:

```
$(".myCheckbox").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("highlightRow");
});
```

And the CSS that might work:

```
.myCheckBox td
{
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this was answered here:

[Highlight a word with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery)

via the jQuery highlight plugin:

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Comment: @silvinci - yes, and I think the jQuery highlight plugin would eliminate the issue.

Comment: But, eliminating the "highlightRow" class in the HTML markup would definitely fix the additional class being added by toggleClass().

Comment: He wanted to highlight a whole table row. I suppose to make clear, that it is selected. Not only paticular words...

Comment: Yes. And you can select a TR or TD via jQuery's selector.  Did you visit the highlight plugin link? Or did you just read the link name from which the answer was obtained?

Comment: Why should he use a massively overloaded plug-in for such a simple operation?

Comment: It's not that big of an operation and I tend to think in larger terms is all.  Would be nice whenever and wherever to simply use `$("#tagId").highlight();` and `$("tagId").removeHighlight();`.